# Bookmark consecutive non-empty lines that start and end with a regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

In following list I want to select consecutive non-empty lines that start and end with `^(?!.*\+\s*$).*?(?<!\d)(?<!\d,)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?!,?\d).*`

```
1,754,085

Bolt

817,653

classmates

cm

623,592

SixDegrees

PlanetAll

361,908

274,553

274,493

1997

SEPTEMBER

021+
```

In above list I want to select only following lines:

```
361,908

274,553

274,493
```

how can I do this by regex in notepad++?

Comment: Why not `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$`? Do you want to say there must be at least two line in a row like that? If yes, then `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\R\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)+`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex select years lines too like 1997

Comment: I just literally copy/pasted your data and regex into notepad++ v8.5.4 and it bookmarks 6 lines: https://i.imgur.com/s2GalEy.png

Comment: Does it mean you want to avoid matching years?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, only comma separated lines and under 1000 numbers

Comment: @KompjoeFriek I told in my post consecutive lines not any lines!

Comment: OK, check my first comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I checked and your regex not working

Comment: `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\R\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)+$`? See https://regex101.com/r/nvBq9N/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do you try your regex in notepad++ and use bookmark feature? or only check in regex101.com?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex is good But you haven't considered the empty lines in my example list!

Comment: Ok, the thing is: you can only bookmark a single line with a regex. The regex is `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\R{2}\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)+$`. See https://regex101.com/r/nvBq9N/2. And now the question is: what are you doing? Why do you want to bookmark anything? What are you going to do with these lines?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it working. please send as answer that I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match two or more lines with a two comma-separated numbers from 0 to 999 separated with double line breaks, you can use

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\R{2}\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nvBq9N/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` - one to three digits and then zero or more occurrences of a comma and three digits
- `(?:\R{2}\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)+` - one or more repetitions of two line break char sequences and then one to three digits and then zero or more occurrences of a comma and three digits
- `$` - end of a line.